# Redirect in Angular 4.2.2 Programmatically

Tags: angular

I'm building a toy app that has a Search page as the default, and then it has an Admin page.  The admin page is called by clicking a button on the Search page.  My code for that process is this:

```
  constructor( private searchResultService: SearchService, private router: Router) {
    ....
  }

  goToAdminLogin(ev): void
  {
    this.router.navigate(['adminLogin'])
  }
```

However, on the click of the Button the only thing that changes is the address bar.

In my app.module.ts, I have this:

```
RouterModule.forRoot([
  {
    path: 'search',
    redirectTo: '/search',
    pathMatch: 'full'
  },
  {
    path: 'adminLogin',
    component: AdminLoginComponent
  }
])
```

[image]

I've checked my console, and I don't see it spewing any error messages.  Does anyone know why my redirect is going nowhere?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

**EDIT:** Adding the AdminLoginComponent:

My AdminLoginComponent looks like this:

```
import {Component, Inject, Input} from '@angular/core';
import {SearchService} from '../services/search.service';
import {SearchResponse} from '../remote/search-response';

@Component({
  selector: 'admin-login-component',
  templateUrl: './admin-login.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./admin-login.component.css']
})
export class AdminLoginComponent {

  constructor( private searchResultService: SearchService)  {
  }
}
```

My 'admin-login.component.html' is very simple and looks like this:

```
<div>Hello</div>
```

**EDIT: Solution**

The solution thanks to Debbie K was to essentially drop my first UI out of my app.component.* and put it in a a sub component, similar to my admin-login setup.  My app.component.html now looks like this:

```
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

Comment: maybe you make AdminLoginComponent by copy the SearchComponent and forget to edit it, so they are the same

Comment: @NhanNguyen I've added the AdminLoginComponent and it appears to have a correctly named constructor.

Comment: When the url changed, that means you have moved to AdminLoginComponent already. just to make it clear, does AdminLoginComponent template look the same with SearchComponent?

Comment: Nope, it looks nothing like the Search component:  I've edited my post.

Comment: do a console.log('somethings') in onInit() function on AdminLoginComponent to see whether it's reached or not

Comment: Do you have a router outlet defined?

Comment: @DeborahK I'm trying to change the whole page.  So would I need a router-outlet defined?

Comment: @DeborahK I added router-outlet to my app.component.html, and it put the page in question where I have <router-outlet> listed.  But I would like to change the whole page to the AdminLogin screen if possible.

Comment: I updated my answer below.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try this:

```
this.router.navigate(['/adminLogin'])
```

And set up a hierarchy of router-outlets:

**app.component.html**

`<router-outlet>` <-- This one will show anything full page.

**home.component.html**

`<header of menu stuff here>`

`<router-outlet>` <-- This one will show anything within the header/footer

`<footer stuff here>`

Does my shorthand here make sense?

Comment: You should mention that the router needs to be injected: import {Router} from '@angular/router';
constructor(private router: Router){}

Answer (score 10):

This involves three simple steps:

1. Import Router

   `import {Router} from '@angular/router';`
2. In constructor

   `constructor(private router: Router){}`
3. Navigate to different router

   `this.router.navigate(['/about']);`

Navigate to an URL

```
`this.router.navigateByUrl('/home');`
```